# multiple layout in a single xml file

Tags: android

I just want to use multiple  layout in a single xml file.I have attached my code below. In that there will be an absolute layout that should be under Horizontal scroll. As a beginner I don't know how to implement it

need your help friends..

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/aagr_background2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/adview153613"
    android:name="com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/aanavigationbar" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_x="8px"
        android:layout_y="3px"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_breaker_bay"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="30px"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/back"
        android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
        android:background="@drawable/home1"
        android:paddingBottom="12px"
        android:paddingTop="10px"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>

<AbsoluteLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="61dp" >
    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_x="120dp"
        android:layout_y="35dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="38dp"
            android:layout_y="30dp"
            android:text="-   Kid Seated"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="6dp"
            android:layout_y="28dp"
            android:src="@drawable/kid" >
        </ImageView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="437dp"
        android:layout_y="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add11_table" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="48dp"
        android:layout_y="4dp"
        android:text="Line"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="128dp"
        android:layout_y="4dp"
        android:text="circle"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="212dp"
        android:layout_y="6dp"
        android:text="vshape"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</AbsoluteLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: sorry dint get your question. can you explain still more clearly?

Comment: In my code there is an absolute layout.The objects inside the layout is in top of the page i need it to be in bottom of the page how can i do this my problem

Comment: absolute layout is very old technology in android. Do not use it, instead user Relative or frame layout to achieve your goal

Comment: while changing from absolute layout to relative layout what are all the changes should be done in java file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use use multiple layouts in single XML using the `<include>`.

Here is a example for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/actionbar_main" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_rest_pic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:src="@drawable/upload_image" />
     </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

The `actionbar_main.xml` file is in different XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/navbar_txt"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtn_action_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/navbar_back" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtn_action_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ibtn_action_back"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/nacbar_setting" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer in my case i need the absolute layout components should be moved to the bottom of the page how can i implement it its my problem you can view my code

Comment: your layout is very much complex, is the all compont are in the same xml or in differnent

Comment: yeah ure write its little bit complex..its in same xml file

Comment: then you can use the weight sum for layout to manage there locations,as like in any view : android:layout_weight="0.2"

Comment: where should i placed it will you say the location from my given code

Comment: The layout weight works like how much screen size it will get from all screen
.. As example we have 0.2 weight then it will contain 20% of device area for that view.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether your looking for this alignment but i just gave a shot..... whenever you wish to fix layout at the **bottom of screen** make sure you use weight property i.e if you want **fix button at the bottom** of screen then put **android:layout_height = "0dp" and layout_weight="1" for other major layout** in the xml and to **button which has to be fixed at the bottom use android:layout_height="wrap_content" and layout_weight = "0"** that's all is the trick (sorry if i have made it hard to understand... just simply saying play with weight and height property)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/adview153613"
        android:name="com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"  >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_x="8px"
            android:layout_y="3px"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="30px"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/back"
            android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12px"
            android:paddingTop="10px"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>



    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/table"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

        <AbsoluteLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_x="120dp"
            android:layout_y="35dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_x="38dp"
                android:layout_y="30dp"
                android:text="-   Kid Seated"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:typeface="serif" >
            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_x="6dp"
                android:layout_y="28dp" >
            </ImageView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="437dp"
            android:layout_y="3dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="48dp"
            android:layout_y="4dp"
            android:text="Line"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="128dp"
            android:layout_y="4dp"
            android:text="circle"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="212dp"
            android:layout_y="6dp"
            android:text="vshape"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you its working i need to do some small changes in it now its working \